# SQL Server 2008 - deleting rows with FK constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, constraints, cascading-deletes

I've got SQL database in SQL Server 2008 generated as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Client ( 
    ID bigint,
    Code varchar(50),
    ClientID int NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE Client 
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Client PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ClientID);

CREATE TABLE Company ( 
    ID bigint,
    Description nvarchar(100),
    SubsidiaryOf bigint,
    companyID int NOT NULL,
    FK_Client_Company int,
    PK_Company int
);
ALTER TABLE Company 
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Company PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (companyID);

ALTER TABLE Company 
  ADD CONSTRAINT (ID = ID) FOREIGN KEY (FK_Client_Company) 
      REFERENCES Client (ClientID);

ALTER TABLE Company 
  ADD CONSTRAINT (SubsidiaryOf = ID) FOREIGN KEY (PK_Company) 
      REFERENCES Company (companyID);

CREATE TABLE ContactData ( 
    ID bigint,
    LocationID bigint,
    Contact nvarchar(50),
    contactDataID int NOT NULL,
    PK_Location int
);
ALTER TABLE ContactData 
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ContactData PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (contactDataID);

ALTER TABLE ContactData 
  ADD CONSTRAINT (LocationID = ID) FOREIGN KEY (PK_Location) 
      REFERENCES Location (locationID);


CREATE TABLE Location ( 
    ID bigint,
    CompanyID bigint,
    Country nvarchar(50),
    ZIPCode nvarchar(50),
    locationID int NOT NULL,
    PK_Company int
);
ALTER TABLE Location 
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Location PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (locationID);

ALTER TABLE Location 
   ADD CONSTRAINT (CompanyID = ID) FOREIGN KEY (PK_Company) 
       REFERENCES Company (companyID);
```

And would like to delete all the Companies with ID > 140000 (with related rows in other tables). I tried some combination of INNER JOINs all together in one transaction, but there is still a problem with FK_Client_Company constraint. Can anyone help me?

One more thing - I cannot add anything/modify DB structure/constraints. It has to be a query-base-solution.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/sql-server-cascade-delete

Comment: You have **very strange** foreign key constraint names.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete those companies' clients

```
    delete client where id in (select fk_client_company from company where id > 140000)
```

After that you should be able to run the delete statement on the company table

```
    delete company where id > 140000
```

I'm 'fairly' sure that's the answer you're looking for but I'm not a 100% positive only because your naming scheme seems a little odd.  I'm making the assumption that company.fk_client_company = client.id.

Comment: You say it has to be a 'query based' solution.  I am assuming you  realize you can modify the database schema with queries, and that you are just saying you don't have access to do that.  If you do in fact have access to do that, then I would recommend adding an 'Active' field to the company table and just mark those companies as inactive.  That may not be a possible solution since maybe you're working with applications you can't change to filter on a new 'Active' field, but I just wanted to throw that out there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've put all this code in BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN

Comment: Oh, I just realized I forgot something. "(select fk_client_company where id > 140000)" should be "(select fk_client_company from company where id > 140000)".  I will fix it in the answer.