# How to get associated tables with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

let's say I have to tables: "Customer" (parent) & "Address" (child). They are associated, so there is a 1:1 relationship between them.

```
   Table<Customer> table = db.GetTable<Customer>();

   var query = from c in table
               select p;
```

Is there a possibility to query against tables that are associated with "Customer" using the selected Customer-tables or do I have to get all Address-tables in a separate query?

Besides if I use a DELETE-command on a Customer-table, does this DELETE all the associated tables too?

Thanks in advance,

Prot

Comment: What's it like on K-PAX?

Comment: We are having a good time up here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are related with a foreign key, then it should be very straight forward.  The Address should just be a property of Customer.

```
var query = from c in table
            select c.Address;
```

Or you could do it with a `join` if a foreign key doesn't exist.

```
var query = from c in table
            join address in [AddressTable] on c.AddressId equals address.Id
            select address;
```

The type of `DELETE` you're referring to is called a cascade delete.  You'll need to enable it on your foreign key (you'll need an FK for this to work).  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/sql-server-cascade-delete).

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to get the address out separately, you should be able to just `lazy load` the address if you have set up an association in the dbml (i.e the arrow linking the tables).

Instellisense should show the property;

```
  var query = from c in table
               select p.Address;
```

for the delete set up an `on delete cascade` on your foreign key on the tables themselves and this will delete the associated address every time you delete a customer record.