# Delete row in sql from table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

Sorry for the title but I didn't know how to name it..

I'm using C# and have a WinForms application
I have 2 tables, each of them have a primary key, those 2 tables are strangers.
It means that I have a third table that connects between them.
the third table have as columns : table's A primary key and table's B primary key.

I just want to know that if I'm deleting one row from the third table, is the related
data from table A and B will be also deleted?

Comment: depends if there is an enforced relationship between the tables and a delete trigger.

Comment: table A have a relationship with the Third table as well as table B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you created a foreign key constraint with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then yes, it will delete the related rows in other tables.

If you created a foreign key constraint WITHOUT the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then the DBMS will prevent you from deleting the original row at all.

If you did not create a foreign key constraint then only the original row will be deleted.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260736/786388) for example usage of the cascading delete option.

Comment: what does it mean ON DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: @Elior I think I explained it pretty clearly. Perhaps you should try googling if you need a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't your third table is just associate table which stores references of table A and B.

But it will have different functionality other way, if a record is deleted in table A and it has any references in associate table C. Depending upon your cascade options, record in table C will also be deleted. If there are no cascade options mentioned, it gives exception.

Comment: so if i'll delete a row from table a, it will delete the reference row from table c and then from table b? or just the rows from tables a and c?

Comment: @Elior, only from table a and c.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server wouldn't let you delete the row from 3rd table because of a Foreign Key constraint.  You'd have to delete the values referencing the 3rd table from table A and B first and then delete from your 3rd table.

Answer (score 0):

No, as the third table is an association table of table a and table b, no records from table a and table b will be deleted, if the deletion is on third table.