# How to delete data in child tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 6 tables named A,B,C,D,E,F

I have A's Primary key,
Now B have ref in A,
C has ref in B,
D has ref in C

E has ref in A,
F has ref in B

Now I want to delete A's records and its related records in other tables and I have only A's primary key,

Best way to delete all records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be safer to add a boolean field name isActive to A, and set it to 0.

Comment: I have think over this, actually it's good but I want to delete records physically too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of

- Use a stored procedure to delete child tables, using WHERE EXISTS
- Set foreign keys to CASCADE DELETE, so all child rows are deleted when you DELETE from A
  See [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/sql-server-cascade-delete)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think Cascade delete has performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the rows in the child tables by SELECTing their foreign key equal to A's primary key, then delete from A using the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If its SQL Server you can set cascade delete to remove related records.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think Cascade delete has performance issues.