# delete from table with foreign keys to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete from a table(`MyTable`) that has a `foreign key` reference linking it to 4 other tables.

I needed to delete all the data `MyTable` that is referenced by `Table1` and `Table2`, but NOT `Table3` and `Table4`. I have already deleted the data in `Table1` and `Table2`

I tried something like this:

```
delete from MyTable where ID NOT IN(SELECT MyTableID FROM Table1)
delete from MyTable where ID NOT IN(SELECT MyTableID FROM Table2)
```

But it obviously doesn't work because if it did it would inadvertently delete the data that `Table2` references.

Is there a way to delete from a table where `FKs` aren't being referenced by certain tables?

Comment: Check out cascading deletes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/sql-server-cascade-delete

Comment: @Ste No, I think that only works the other way around. I believe OP wants to delete rows which has a PK which isn't referenced in the FK of other tables.

Comment: @Dukeling - Ah, my bad.  Should have done more than skimmed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Rewritten answer to SQL Server syntax after some basic research and finding [The DELETE statement in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-delete-statement-in-sql-server/).)

Use the multiple table syntax of the `DELETE` statement.

```
DELETE
  MyTable
FROM
  MyTable
  LEFT JOIN Table1 ON MyTable.ID = Table1.MyTableID
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON MyTable.ID = Table2.MyTableID
  LEFT JOIN Table3 ON MyTable.ID = Table3.MyTableID
  LEFT JOIN Table4 ON MyTable.ID = Table4.MyTableID
WHERE
  (Table1.MyTableID IS NOT NULL OR Table2.MyTableID IS NOT NULL)
  AND Table3.MyTableID IS NULL
  AND Table4.MyTableID IS NULL
```

The `DELETE` will only operate on the table *before* the `FROM` clause. You can select rows using other tables in the `FROM` clause which will not be affected. This example joins `MyTable` with all the tables that you mention and then checks for each row that either `Table1` or `Table2` refer to the row *and* that `Table3` and `Table4` do not refer to the row.

Comment: Note that the OP tagged the question as SQL Server.

Comment: @PaulWilliams: thanks for the heads up on the added tag. I have rewritten (changed two lines) in the query to make it work on SQL Server (which is incidentally still valid MySQL syntax as well).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not too efficient, but the below should work.

It should "delete all the data [in] MyTable that is referenced by Table1 and Table2, but NOT Table3 and Table4". Your query seems to not exactly match up with desiring to do this.

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE
  ID IN (SELECT MyTableID FROM Table1) AND
  ID IN (SELECT MyTableID FROM Table2) AND
  ID NOT IN (SELECT MyTableID FROM Table3) AND
  ID NOT IN (SELECT MyTableID FROM Table4)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is @ThomaCreemers 's convverted to `SQL Server` syntax

```
DELETE MyTable
FROM MyTable
  LEFT JOIN Table1 ON MyTable.ID = Table1.MyTableID
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON MyTable.ID = Table2.MyTableID
  LEFT JOIN Table3 ON MyTable.ID = Table3.MyTableID
  LEFT JOIN Table4 ON MyTable.ID = Table4.MyTableID
WHERE
  (Table1.MyTableID IS NOT NULL OR Table2.MyTableID IS NOT NULL)
  AND Table3.MyTableID IS NULL
  AND Table4.MyTableID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
delete from MyTable
where 1=1
    AND ID NOT IN(SELECT MyTableID FROM Table1)
    AND ID NOT IN(SELECT MyTableID FROM Table2)
```