# SQL, How to delete rows from related tables using a query?

Tags: sql

I have the following tables

```
    vehicle (veh_num(PK), veh_desc)
    log (log_num(PK), veh_num(FK), log_date, log_complaint)
    log_line (log_num(PK,FK), logline_num(PK), emp_id(FK), logline_date,logline_action)
    part (part_code(PK), logline_num(FK), log_num(FK), part_desc)
    signout (signout_num(PK), part_code(FK), emp_id(FK), log_num(FK), signout_date)
```

I want to run a query which will delete all the records in the vehicle table with for instance, veh_num = "EK458" and also delete rows which are related to the veh_num in the other tables.

I have started with the following query,

```
    DELETE FROM signout WHERE EXISTS
    (select * from vehicle,log,log_line,part
    where 
    vehicle.veh_num = 'EK458'  AND
    vehicle.veh_num = log.veh_num AND
    log.log_num = log_line.log_num AND
    log_line.log_num = part.log_num AND 
    part.part_code = signout.part_code);
```

This query deletes all the associated values of veh_num = "EK458" in the signout table, however, I want a query which will delete the rows from the all the tables which are related to veh_num.
Thanks in advance

Comment: DELETE t1,t2,t3 FROM vehicle as t1
JOIN log as t2 ON t2.veh_num = t1.veh_num
JOIN log_line as t3 ON t3.veh_num = t1.veh_num                      Join part as t4 ON t4.veh_num = t1.veh_num                      Join Signout as t5 ON t5.veh_num = t1.veh_num

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is having the delete cascade into other tables.

Take a look at this [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/sql-server-cascade-delete)

Answer (score 0):

Read this link http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-integrity-constraints.htm
and have you tried join instead of subquery in query?

Comment: can add a foreing key and dont worry about children deletion
https://www.sqlshack.com/delete-cascade-and-update-cascade-in-sql-server-foreign-key/

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to use a query, you'll need to write multiple delete queries, deleting first from the outermost tables of the relationship hierarchy and working your way in, often in layers/sets of tables, to the primary table.

Answered here too:  [How do I delete all related records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516933/how-do-i-delete-all-related-records)