# Add Cascade to exist table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have db in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have table `Users` and some child tables that have foreign key relationships to `UserID`.

I forgot to add on cascade delete and update in the creation.

There is a way to do it now, without losing the data?

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/sql-server-cascade-delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to drop the key and re-add it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE someTable DROP FOREIGN KEY someID;
ALTER TABLE someTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (someID) REFERENCES someOtherTable (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I hope this helps.