# MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been working on MySQL for the past few months.
Kindly apologize if my question is silly.

We have Foreign key Checks,

Enable   - `SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

Disable  - `SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS,FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

Similarly,

Do we have any Query to Enable and Disable `ON DELETE CASCADE` in MySQL?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new foreign key constraint using :

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
     FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

or alter the existing constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
   FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks. But can i disable the "ON DELETE CASCADE" once added without being removed???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to

drop the existing foreign key constraint
add a new one with the ON DELETE CASCADE setting enabled

Comment: Thanks. But can i disable the "ON DELETE CASCADE" once added without being removed???

Comment: ON DELETE CASCADE is part of a constraint, so it can't be disabled separately. You need to disable the constraint itself.

Comment: Thanks alot Nikhil Talreja. :-) :-D