# How do I get Navigation Properties working?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have the following entities:

```
public abstract class Meter
{
    public int MeterId { get; set; }
    public string EANNumber { get; set; }
    public string MeterNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Premise Premise { get; set; }
    public abstract void AddReading(CounterReading reading);
}

public class GasMeter : Meter
{
    public virtual Counter Counter { get; private set; }

    public override void AddReading(CounterReading reading)
    {
        Counter.Readings.Add(reading);
    }
}

public class Premise
{
    [Key]
    public int PremiseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual GasMeter GasMeter { get; set; }
}
```

I have a 1:1 relation between a `GasMeter` and a `Premise`.

What must I do so that I can set `myPremise.GasMeter = myMeter`, and retrieve `myPremise` in later code with `myMeter.Premise`?

**Edit**
When setting it up via the Fluent API as follows:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Premise>().HasOptional(p => p.GasMeter)
            .WithRequired(m => m.Premise);
    }
```

I get the following exception when running:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Premise: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'Premise' is not valid. Type 'GasMeter' of FromRole 'Premise_GasMeter_Target' in AssociationType 'Premise_GasMeter' must exactly match with the type 'Meter' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.

Does this mean that I can't use Navigation Properties with inheritance?
How would I solve my problem then?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27727545/861716

Comment: Either `public virtual Premise Premise { get; set; }` should be in `GasMeter` or `public virtual GasMeter GasMeter` should be `public virtual Meter Meter`.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, I put the Premise in my GasMeter. I have multiple Meters on my Premise (GasMeter, WaterMeter, ElectricityMeter) and would like to keep the type safety there.

Comment: @GertArnold Putting the `Premise` property on my Meter makes my MeterId wrong. EF doesn't auto-increment the MeterId anymore then.

Comment: No, `Premise` is the principle entity, `Meter` only copies `Premise`'s PK value, it doesn't generate its own. So both always have the same PK (and `Meter`'s PK is also an FK to `Premise`). That's how it works with 1:1.

Comment: @GertArnold Then I think I'm wrong, because besides my `GasMeter`, I also have a Water- and ElectricityMeter on my Premise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the Id to each class for PK/FK relationship

```
public abstract class Meter
{
   ....
    public int PremiseId
    public virtual Premise Premise { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Premise
{
   ....
   public int GasMeterId
   public virtual GasMeter GasMeter{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: After I add my premise to my meter, I still don't see the meter on my premise. Even with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to link these two entities as virtual properties within each other. Try modify Meter class to keep the PremiseId since it is the primary key of Premise table then get the Premise entity using `Select(x => x.PremiseId == aMeter.PremiseId).SingleOrDefault()` to get the Premise mapped to this GasMeter

```
public abstract class Meter
{
    public int MeterId { get; set; }
    public string EANNumber { get; set; }
    public string MeterNumber { get; set; }
    public int PremiseId { get; set; }
    public abstract void AddReading(CounterReading reading);
}
```

SET

```
var aPremise = new Premise();
var aMeter = new GasMeter();
aPremise.GasMeter = aMeter;
aMeter.PremiseId = aPremise.PremiseId;
```

GET

```
var thePremise = _repository.Set<Premise>.Select(x => x.PremiseId == aMeter.PremiseId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Using it like that defeats the point of having navigation properties.