# i can't create relationship in my database sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

i have 3 table, user, topic and comment. I design database for my website. One user has many topic (or article) One topic (or article) has many comment One user has many comment

i create relationship for them. after i set Insert and And Update Specification as cascade.

I want if i delete one user then topic of this user and comment of user will delete If i delete one topic then all comment of topic will delete by cascade

[image: my diagram]

Comment: you can check for `triggers`.

Comment: i do'nt know. now i must use T-SQL @@

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server Sounnd similar to what you describe

Comment: conflict if i set cascade for comment users

Answer (score 0):

@lecuong92....

- While creating the relationship between the tables ...  you should mention delete cascade....
- Then, once you delete the records of parent table, then records from the child table will automatically get deleted....
- Use : "ON DELETE CASCADE" clause