# Best practice for deleting many-to-many relationships with SQL Server and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, triggers, relationships

I'm working on a project in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework linked to a SQL Server database, to which I use SQL Server Management Studio to manage.

I have some many-to-many relationships that I handle with an intermediate table that links the two other tables. Let's say I have table A, table B and table A_B that links the A and B in a many to many relationship.

If I want to delete a row in table A, I must delete all rows in table B that links with it, therefore deleting the rows in A_B.

**My question is**:

What's the best practice in this case? Should I handle those deletes in the controller in MVC ASP.NET or must I handle this with a SQL Server trigger?

To me it would look cleaner to just use a trigger and abstracting all this logic from the controller itself, so I would only need to delete the row in table A and the lower lever (SQL Server) would take care of the rest.

But, I've heard people saying that we should avoid triggers in SQL Server, so in a commercial project, which approach would you recommend as being the best practice?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

[TABLE A [id]] -> [ TABLE A_B [id_A, id_B, position] ] <- [TABLE B [id]]

That's the situation I have (I can't post images yet). I've tried to put Cascade on Delete on every relationship, but when I delete a row in A, the corresponding row in A_B get's deleted but not the corresponding table in B. Is there a way to do this? Or in this case I have to use triggers?

Comment: You could also just use [cascade delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server). There is no best practice. It depends on various factors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to force **SQL Server** to delete references you should use [`CASCADE DELETE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx) not triggers, just because it's more obvious way to do it. You should switch on it on `FOREIGN KEY` creation.

If you already created the `FOREIGN KEY` then drop it first.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.B
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A_B_Cascade
FOREIGN KEY (AId) REFERENCES dbo.A(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But it's much better set your deletion logic in code. Because not in all cases you want to delete references. Sometimes it's better just set some flag like `IsDeleted` to `true`.

Moreover it's better not doing this in `Controller`, but create separate **DAL** (Data Access Layer) project and place it there. And can be that you want to use one of **ORM** like [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) to access your DB.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to apply the Cascade rule to the Delete action and the problem is:

When I delete a row in A, the row in A_B get's deleted but not the row in B. Remind that A has no foreign key to B, and B has no foreign key to A, everything is mapped by the table A_B.

Comment: I read again your answer and when trying to implement it on the database I started to notice that I may be overthinking this and maybe this is more of a design problem. The cascading rule should be enough for this. Thanks for the help, and also for the tip on coding the logic for this in the DAL.

Comment: Can you just please check the edit I made to the main question. I think the situation is more clear now.

Comment: Don't use triggers - that's what i suggest. Trigges is not easy to maintain in future. Just put that logic in the stored procedure where you deleting your record.

Comment: Hum, ok. I though that there could be a simple constraint or something that would add another level of 'security'. I will then put the code to delete all related row in the DAL. Thanks for your time.