# Oracle to SQL Server Migration issue - On delete cascade

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

Folks,

I am working on Oracle to MS SQL Server migration. One of the issue I came across is that "ON DELETE CASCADE" works fine in Oracle, but not in SQL Server.
Is there any alternative to the syntax/command or is it something we need to manually remove/fix it.

Could not get a valid link/reference on web, hence requesting here.
If this is already answered, please help re-directing to the appropriate page.

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server expert, but I'm pretty sure there is no such error message as "*does not work*" in SQL Server. Show us your code and the exact error message you get.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server) Answer will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `ON DELETE CASCADE` is supported in SQL Server too. Following is the syntax:

- Create table

```
    CREATE TABLE child_table
    (
      column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
      column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
      ...

      CONSTRAINT fk_name
        FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
        REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

- Alter table

```
    ALTER TABLE child_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name
        FOREIGN KEY (child_col1, child_col2, ... child_col_n)
        REFERENCES parent_table (parent_col1, parent_col2, ... parent_col_n)
        ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

See an example [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php).

Comment: I got it now.. Thanks. But another issue came up. I need to use a circular reference to the same table, but different column. Is it something that can be in sql server or move the respective logic to application code ?

Comment: @RoopeshMajeti Please ask a new question for that, and next time please post some sample data and what you tried. Please mark it as answered, would help others.