# Deleting tables with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables

```
GroupTable
GroupId
Name
```

Each group has a one to many with Users

```
Users
UserId
Name
GroupId
```

And each User has one to many with 'Challenges'

```
Challenges
Name
UserId
```

I want to be able to delete a group with the users assigned to that specific group

I have tried this where I do manage to delete the Group based on id without getting a foreign key constraint error but ALL the users added to the user table and ALL the challenges get deleted as well

```
ALTER TABLE GroupTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE UserTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
ALTER TABLE Challanges NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

DELETE FROM GroupTable
WHERE ID = @GroupId

DELETE FROM child
FROM Challanges as child
INNER JOIN UserTable AS parent
ON child.UserId = parent.ID
WHERE parent.GroupId = @GroupId

DELETE FROM parent
FROM UserTable AS parent
WHERE GroupId = GroupId
```

How can I ammend the above so that I only delete the gropu with the specific Users and there challenges assigned to the Group?

Comment: Umm... `DELETE FROM parent FROM UserTable AS parent WHERE GroupId = GroupId` has to be a typo? Surely you want `GroupId = @GroupId`?

Comment: Just saw that now...that could bet the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not disable the constraints for this, as it will compromise data integrity.
Either use [`on delete cascade`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) option on the foreign keys, or delete the data from all three tables in the correct order, inside a single transaction.
To add `on cascade delete` to an existing foreign key you must use the `alter table` statement to drop the existing constraint and then add it again with the `on delete cascade` option:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name

ALTER TABLE table_name
   ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
   FOREIGN KEY (column_name) 
      REFERENCES other_table_name(other_column_name) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

(of course, this can be done [using ssms's design table window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228623/3094533))

Deleting the rows from the related tables in the correct order will ensure you will encounter no problems with the existing foreign key constraints, wrapping all the delete statement in a single transaction will ensure you will only delete from every table or none at all:

```
DECLARE @GroupId int = 5

BEGIN TRY

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE c
FROM Challanges c
INNER JOIN UserTable u ON(c.UserId = u.UserId)
WHERE u.GroupId = @GroupId

DELETE 
FROM Users
WHERE GroupId = @GroupId

DELETE 
FROM GroupTable
WHERE ID = @GroupId

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```