# Delete from multiple related tables on one id?

Tags: sql

I have three tables.

- Table 1 (table1_id, table1_name)
- Table 2 (table2_id, table1_id, table2_name)
- Table 3 (table3_id, table2_id, table3_name)

I want to delete all the information where `table1_id = 33`. How I also delete all table2 rows that have `table1_id = 33` and also all table3 rows that have table2_id whose rows in Table 2 have  `table1_id = 33`? What is the nicest and proper way to do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sql server then you can go for option "Cascade Delete".
Use this option for Table1 and Table2 it should work.

[How to use Cascade Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Comment: This is available in most databases.

Comment: OK..Thanks Gordon for sharing information..I was not sure about it.