# TSQL, delete row and all foreign key related rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering if there is a query for deleting a row which also deletes all related foreign key related data.

I have a database with a table which refers through a foreign key to other rows in the same table

```
ID  |  ParentID  |  Data fields
1   |  NULL      |  text and more data
2   |  1         |  Text and more data
3   |  2         |  ""
```

As you see item 2 refers to 1 using a foreign key. Currently I am unable to delete object 1 because object 2 and 3 still exist in the database. I want to know if there is a way/query (without changing the table settings) to delete object 1 and therefore also deleting 2 and 3.

```
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID = 1 -- And this must then also delete row 2.
DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID = 1 OR ParentID = 1 -- Obviously doesn't work either.
```

I am aware that it is possible to turn of foreign key constrainst for a table, but I want to know if it can be done with a query without changing these settings.

Comment: Use ON DELETE CASCADE at the end of the delete statement

Comment: @AshimDas: `on delete cascade` is an option for `add constraint ... foreign key`, not for the `delete` statement

Comment: yes. I apologize. Cascade Delete will be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be enabling `CASCADE DELETE`.
Read more here: [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)