# sql delete record from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 2 tables in sql server (I did not create these tables but I have to work with them):

```
document
 - document_id
 - created_date

trade_document
 - trade_document_id
 - document_id *foreign key to document table
```

Today, I added a bunch of new `trade_document` records (which automatically creates the related `document_id`, this is done using an `ORM`), but I want to delete all these records.

I want to do the deletes relative to the `added_date` in the `document` table

> where created_date > yesterday

I also want the related `document` record to be deleted.

I'm not very good with sql, all I have so far is a basic template that doesn't do much:

```
DELETE FROM db.schema.trade_document (I'm guessing some sort of join on document)
WHERE document.created_date > 11/10/15
```

> it doesn't haven't to be one statement, could be multiple

Comment: Does it have to be one delete statement? Why not delete the trade_document first, and then the document?

Comment: You cant delete from two tables in a single select.

Comment: @JoseM I don't care how many statements there are. But my question is mainly, how do I delete from `trade_document` relative to a date in the document table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two delete statment and in this order.

```
 DELETE FROM db.schema.trade_document
 WHERE document_id IN (SELECT document_id
                       FROM document
                       WHERE created_date > 11/10/15);


 DELETE FROM db.schema.document
 WHERE created_date > 11/10/15);
```

For your reference you can also create your table using `DELETE CASCADE`

[How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Comment: I know you didnt create the table, but i add the info for clause `DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: yea no problem, I want to get better with sql so it's very helpful!

Comment: is that date format correct? I think I accidentally deleted all trade_document records lol. what's the default sql server date format?

Comment: use `convert` function to make sure you use the right format http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp Should be format 3 or 10

Comment: one more question :) is there a way to undo the delete that I did? if not its ok, its a test database. (I didn't use a transaction)

Comment: Sorry hear that. Check this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/995/how-do-i-get-back-some-deleted-records. Also you should always test your delete using a select first.