# Looping in SQL to get all entries in a table associated with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that holds data about exported bills. Each bill has a vendor. There is a separate table which has items from that bill.

So there are multiple bills for a vendor and then again multiple line items per bill.

I'm not sure how to delete a vendor from the database. I need to loop through the bill table. Then for each bill that has that vendor I need to use that bill ID to delete all line items with that bill ID from the line items table.

I just don't know how I loop through the bill table and act on each bill id. If anyone could offer an explanation on how i do it that would be great. Cheers

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: You should provide a db schema and sample data. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your tables to include [DELETE CASCADE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

[How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Or delete in sequence

I understand Vendors has Bills and Bills has Items.

```
DELETE I
FROM Items I 
JOIN Bills B
  ON B.bill_id = I.bill_id    
WHERE B.vendor_id = @VendorID; 

DELETE B
FROM Bills B
WHERE B.vendor_id = @VendorID; 

DELETE V
FROM Vendor V
WHERE V.vendor_id = @VendorID;
```

Comment: Cheers man thanks. I never heard of the Cascade option before. As for the question, I asked it that way as I didnt want an exact answer, I wanted just a general description and then go work it out. I know that sounds awkward but i think its better to learn that way. Cheers again for the help