# Delete from 2 tables using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have 3 tables.

- InvoiceOriginal
- Invoice
- InvoiceHistory

the invoice table has a foreign key constraint.
Each entry in the invoice table has a corresponding entry in Invoiceoriginal.

The invoiceOriginal table stores the original values of the invoice and invoice table stores the values which have been modified by the user.
this is done to get diferrences at the time of submission.

the SQL I am using is

```
DELETE i
FROM invoice i
INNER JOIN InvoiceHistory aih
   ON i.ClientId = aih.HistoryClientNumber
   AND i.invoiceNumber = HistoryInvoiceNumber
```

however deletion is not possible because of foreign Key constraint.

The table is as under:

```
Invoice         InvoiceOriginal         InvoiceHistory
 Id                FK_InvoiceId            ClientId
 ClientId          ClientId                InvoiceNumber
 InvoiceNumber
```

I need to delete the entry in invoice and InvoiceOriginal once there is an entry for that invoice number in InvoiceHistory for the same clientId.

Comment: if required the delete in a single query use the  ON DELETE CASCADE in table schema. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server

Comment: Please check my answer as accepted, you can do both deletions in one query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot issue a delete statement against more than one table at a time, you need to have individual delete statements for each of the related tables before deleting the parent record(s)

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure you can't delete from multiple tables with a single statement.  I would normally delete the child rows first with one statement and then delete the parent record.  You may wish to do this inside a transaction if you might need to roll back on failure.

Alternatively, you could enable CASCADE ON DELETE on the foreign key which would automatically cascade the deletions through the child records if that is something that is suitable for this system.

Comment: Can you please provide syntax on CASCADE ON DELETE

Comment: You set it up on the foreign key https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188066.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the records from multiple table from a single query. But you have two methods to solve this

1. Delete all the related records from child or mapping table, and then
   delete the Parent / header table record. (Multiple queries required here. Use [SQL Transaction](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm) for a better control).
2. Or, Modify your foreign key constraint to [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Answer (score -4):

Yes, **YOU CAN**, I did it right now:

```
DELETE T1,T2 FROM T1
        INNER JOIN
    T2 ON T2.FIELD = T1.FIELD
WHERE
    T1.SOMETHING='SOMETHING'
```

Comment: I can assure you this does not work on sql server and he is talking about mysql