# How to create a trigger for delete from referenced tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Hello we have recently learned how to create triggers and I have to do one on delete from Users, which also deletes said user from referenced tables but I don't know how to make it in SQL server (we had to choose a DB Management system and I chose sql server) but I recently learned you can't do triggers before the action so I don't know how to solve this, I had something like

```
create trigger myTrigger
on User
for delete
AS
delete from GroupParticipants where participantId in (select deleted.codUser from Deleted)
delete from (...) where column in (select deleted.codUser from Deleted)
GO
```

Yet, as this happens after the delete, said delete never occurs due to referential integrity, how do I solve this seemingly simple problem?

My tables are something like this:

> User (codUser, ...)
>
> GroupParticipant (groupId, codUser)
>
> OtherTable(codUser)

and other irrelevant tables

Comment: Have you looked at an [instead of delete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to re-do the constraints to use cascade delete (this way, you won't need a trigger):  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260736/3394342

Comment: I don't get it if this happens after delete how will I be able to delete the user on the first place if sql management will give me an integrity error before the trigger even triggers