# memsql multi-table delete, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, singlestore

MEMSQL! I want to delete a record in a table that has a match in another table on multiple fields. Is this possible?

The MySql query I would use could be something like:

```
delete from t1 used t1,t2 where t1.f1=t2.f1 and t1.f2=t2.f2
```

or

```
delete t1 from t1,t2 where...
```

According to http://docs.memsql.com/docs/delete :

> MemSQL does not yet fully support multi-table DELETE statements.
>   Subqueries in the WHERE clause are the only multi-table DELETE
>   allowed.

Can I use multiple conditions in delete where clause with out concat, etc?

P.S. Sorry for my terrible english

Comment: Possible [Duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
delete from t1 where exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.f1=t2.f1 and t1.f2=t2.f2)
```

Comment: Thx for answer! For Select it worked. But delete got error
"'correlated subselect that can not be transformed and does not match on shard keys' is not supported by memsql Distributed"

Comment: MemSQL currently has limited support for these query shapes if the joins are cross-shard. If you can make t1 and t2's shard keys include (f1, f2) then it should work. Another solution is making either of t1 and t2 a reference table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with trying to update some fields of a table from another table.

The problem is that ***Correlated subselect that can not be transformed and does not match on shard keys' is not supported by MemSQL Distributed***
So my solution was to create a select query that generates update queries and then to run them. Here is a simplified generator query:

```
select concat('update table1 set t1_code=\'',t2_code,
    '\',t1_url=\'',t2_url,
    '\',t1_width=\'',t2_width,
    '\' where t1.id=',t2.id,';') query
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.id=t1.id;
```

that generates update query for each row that needs update separated by `;`.

Generating delete will be even easier - you can just select the ids to be deleted and generate a query `delete from t1 where id in (-the list of ids that was selected for deletion-)`

That was my workaround for this memsql restriction.