# Entity Framework Cascade delete doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

For some reason I'm not able to use Cascade Delete with Entity Framework. I'm trying to automatically delete a row of "Players" when I delete one of "HighScoreListEntry", but even if the SQL Code looks fine it does only delete the row in the HighScoreListEntry table.

```
public class Player
{
    //Navigation Property
    public List<HighScoreListEntry> HSLEs { get; set; }

    //Properties
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public String FName { get; set; }
    public String LName { get;  set; }

    public Player(String fName, String lName)
    {
        FName = fName;
        LName = lName;
    }

    public Player()
    {

    }
}

public class HighScoreListEntry
{
    //Navigation Property
    [Required]
    public Player Player { get; set; }

    //Foreign key
    public int PlayerID { get; set; }

    //Properties
    [Key]
    public int HSLEId { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public HighScoreListEntry(Player player, TimeSpan duration, DateTime time, int value)
    {
        if (value < 0) throw new FormatException();
        Player = player;
        Duration = duration;
        Time = time;
        Value = value;
    }

    public HighScoreListEntry()
    {

    }
}
```

HighScoreListEntry DDL Code

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HighScoreListEntries] (
    [HSLEId]   INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PlayerID] INT      NOT NULL,
    [Duration] TIME (7) NOT NULL,
    [Time]     DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Value]    INT      NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.HighScoreListEntries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([HSLEId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.HighScoreListEntries_dbo.Players_PlayerID] FOREIGN KEY ([PlayerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Players] ([PlayerId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PlayerID]
    ON [dbo].[HighScoreListEntries]([PlayerID] ASC);
```

I know the method name isn't the best but that's not the problem

```
    public bool edit(HighScoreListEntry entryOld, HighScoreListEntry entryNew)
    {
        try
        {
            db.HSLE.Remove(entryOld);
            db.HSLE.Add(entryNew);
            db.SaveChanges();
        } catch (Exception f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not work the way you expected.

When you remove `HighScoreListEntry`, no `Player` entity is removed as it is parent one. If you were removing an `Player` all `HighScoreListEntry` entities belonging to the removed player would be deleted as well.

See related question for reference - [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)