# SQL trigger to delete from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

**Products**:

```
Product ID | Quantity
```

**OrdersLines**:

```
Product ID | Amount --(multiple lines with the same ID)
```

Naturally, before I delete the product from the `Products` table, I need to delete all order lines with that product id first from the `OrdersLines` table.

So I wrote a trigger to do it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[atbl_Sales_Products_DTrig]
ON [dbo].[atbl_Sales_Products]
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM atbl_sales_OrdersLines
    WHERE ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM deleted)
END
```

However, when I try do delete in the form from Products table, it still says:

> There are rows in a related table (Sales OrdersLines) that must be removed before this row can be deleted

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT as per request: Main constraint:

```
[dbo].[atbl_Sales_OrdersLines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_atbl_Sales_OrdersLines_atbl_Sales_Products] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[atbl_Sales_Products] ([ProductID])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a [cascading delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260736/300836)?

Comment: Yes, i know that this would fix the problem. However, im doing this for assignment. It needs to be solved in a trigger.

Comment: Trigger (it is called `AFTER` trigger) is executed after the delete operation in the table, hence the error message. What you need is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, they are a bit trickier to get right. Read the whole article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in this case is that trigger was created as `FOR DELETE` trigger. So it's fired after delete operation - which cause error.

You should create it as `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger and it will solve this problem.

Second problem is that you shouldn't use `=` in subquery bacause it can return more then one row. You should use `IN` operator.

You can see example below which cause error for both problems.

```
INSERT INTO Products(ProductId, Quantity)
SELECT 1,1
UNION
SELECT 2,2
GO

INSERT INTO OrdersLines(ProductId,Amount)
SELECT 1,2
UNION
SELECT 1,3
UNION
SELECT 2,4
UNION
SELECT 2,5
GO

DELETE Products
GO
```

This will pass when the trigger is fine.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Just a little comment, i needed to write an additional query to delete from the products table as well.