# SQLite EF6 Cascade delete on Many to Many

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have the following two classes:

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Process> Processes { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        this.Processes = new HashSet<Process>();
    }
}
```

and

```
[Table("Processes")]
public class Process
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }


    //list of all products
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public Process()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
}
```

As you can see, One product can have multiple processes and one process can be bound to multiple products. (e.g. product **Chair** consists of the following processes: **Cutting**, **Drilling**, **Screwing**, etc...

Under my `OnModelCreating` method in my `DataContext` I have specified Many to Many relationships as follows:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Process>()
            .HasMany<Product>(s => s.Products)
            .WithMany(c => c.Processes)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("Process_ProcessId");
                cs.MapRightKey("Product_ProductId");
                cs.ToTable("ProcessProducts");
            });
```

Which creates a new table named `ProcessProducts` where many to many relationships are being stored.

My Problem now is, that when I remove e.g. Product from my database, I would like to automatically remove all rows from `ProcessProducts` table, where the particular `ProductId` has been used. I wanted to configure `CascadeDelete` under my modelBuilder, but it does not allow me to do so.

Maybe it's the way, how I am removing the item which is wrong?

```
    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Any help in regards to this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do delete in cascade mode you can use [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server) or [EF](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx).

Each case need to be configured how deep the cascade will go. So the question is: How deep you want to go:

If you delete a `Product` should delete de `Process(es)` connected with it and if this `Process(es)` has other `Product(s)` should cascade keep this chain of deletion?

Perhaps by cascade delete, you only meant delete the connection (many-to-many relationship) between `Product` and `Process`. If this is the case you only need to do:

```
public void DeleteProduct(Product entity)
{
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
    entity = _context.Set<Product>().First(f => f.Id == entity.Id);
    _context.Set<Product>().Remove(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This should delete your `Product` and all `ProcessProducts` registries connected with your `Product`.