# Orphaned Rows in databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I was trying to understand the concept of orphaned rows in a database and how they can be found and removed.

Say for example you had 2 tables (person,dog) and there was a 1-to-1 relationship between them so every person must have a dog and every dog must have an owner.

Person table:

```
 ID      Name   
 1       James
 2       Matt
 3       Mike
```

Dog table:

```
 ID Name Owner_id
 1   Sam    1
 2   Rex    2
 3   Max    3
 4   Fred   4
```

Now if i joined those tables with:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Person P
 FULL OUTER JOIN Dog D ON P.id = D.Owner_id
```

This would produce a result where dog (fred) doesnt have an owner and just appears as NULL.

Is this therefore an orphaned row as it should have a matching owner?

Is this only caused due to no primary/foreign keys?

How can orphaned rows been found in a database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You sort of answered your own question.  But I would use the following left join to find the orphaned rows:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Dog d
LEFT JOIN Person p
    ON d.Owner_id = p.ID
WHERE
    p.ID IS NULL;
```

This would return every dog record which does not have a matching owner.

One way to avoid situations like this would be to employ foreign key constraints(like, Cascade Delete - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)).  With such constraints it would not be possible to delete an owner record if certain dog records were still referencing that owner.

I hope that this answer helps you to avoid barking up the wrong tree (woof).

Comment: Yes, i understand thanks. What is the easiest method to find orphaned rows?

Comment: Well I might prefer the above answer because it is conceptually clean.  You could also try using `EXISTS`, which might perform a bit faster.