# Delete from multiple tables in single select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete record from table `foo`, but it has many FK's with reference constraints to other tables. I **don't have CASCADE** set on. Can I do it one query? Something like:

```
delete f, b
from foo f
left join bar b on b.fooID = f.ID
where f.ID = 11764
```

Comment: No. It can't be done in one query if you don't have cascade set on.  You'll need to delete the rows in the table that references your table first.

Comment: then maybe there is some other more practical way instead of manually changing allias after `delete` statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your query into something like:

```
DECLARE @fooId INT = 11764;

DELETE FROM bar 
WHERE fooID = @fooID

DELETE FROM foo
WHERE ID = @fooId
```

By first declaring the `@fooId` variable the code easier to reuse if you want to delelte more than one item.

If you want to delete many items, according to some condition, you could declare a table variable where you put the ids:

```
DECLARE @deleteItems TABLE
(
    ID INT
);

INSERT INTO @deleteItems (ID)
    SELECT ID FROM foo WHERE <your conditions here>

DELETE FROM Bar 
WHERE FooID in (SELECT ID FROM @deleteItems)

DELETE FROM Foo 
WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM @deleteItems)
```

It might also be appropriate to put `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at the beginning and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` at the end to make sure that the updates are atomic