# How to apply cascade delete on entities which have several foreign keys with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, cascade

I have the two entities below:

```
[Table("TimeZone")]
public class TimeZone
{
    [Required]
    [Column("Name"), Index("IX_Name", IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("Description")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column("IANAID"), Index("IX_IANAID", IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string IANAId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    public TimeZone()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
}

[Table("User")]
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{ 
    // [...]

    [Column("TimeZoneID"), ForeignKey("TimeZone")]
    public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    [Column("RegionID"), ForeignKey("Region")]
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
    [Column("ManagerID"), ForeignKey("Manager")]
    public string ManagerId { get; set; }

    // One-to-One
    public virtual TimeZone TimeZone { get; set; }

    // One-to-One
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    // One-to-Many
    public virtual ApplicationUser Manager { get; set; }

    // One-to-many
    public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    // Many-to-many
    public virtual ICollection<OnCallGroup> OnCallGroups { get; set; }

    // One-to-many
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Subordinates { get; set; }
}
```

When I delete a record from `TimeZone` table which is used in the `User` table, the related records should be deleted according to the Cascadde Delete convention.

However since there are other foreign keys, I get the following exception with Entity Framework:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.User_dbo.TimeZone_TimeZoneID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "APPLICATIONDB_753c3d2ad2634cbf8cb62b098cdc6043", table
>   "dbo.User", column 'TimeZoneID'. The statement has been terminated.

Is it normal that even though there is the cascade delete enabled by default on EF6 Code First, deleting a record from `TimeZone` does not delete all the related users?

Note:
In my ApplicationDbContext I overrided the `OnModelCreating` method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(dbModelBuilder);

        dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Add<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();


        // [...]
    }
```

Comment: You can set this cascade delete on database side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server/6260736#answer-25228623

Comment: @AnkushJain it's not supposed to work regardless of the database...
The database is created through the ApplicationDbContext in which I force / add the CascadeDeleteConvention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FK property (`TimeZoneId`) CLR type is `string`, which allows `null`, and no `[Required]` attribute has been applied to the FK or navigation property, thus making the relationship **optional**, i.e. `ApplicationUser` may exist without `TimeZone`. And by default convention EF does not turn cascade delete on optional relationships.

To turn the cascade delete on, you need either to make the relationship **required** by applying the `[Required]` attribute on either `TimeZoneId` or `TimeZone` property, or use fluent API in case you need to keep it optional by adding the following inside `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TimeZone>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Users)
    .WithOptional(e => e.TimeZone)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.TimeZoneId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(); // <--
```

The same applies to other relationships using `string` FK properties.

**Update:** Actually the second option is not really an option. Even if it sets cascade delete on, EF treats cascade delete on optional relationships differently - when principal entity is deleted, it disassociates the related records by setting FKs to `null` rather than deleting them. So you really have to make the relationship required by using the aforementioned attribute or changing the fluent API `WithOptional` to `WithRequired`.