# How to delete data from two tables?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two tables `teacher` and `student`. Different teachers have students. when I delete one teacher then student related to that teacher should also be deleted.
Student have StudentTeacherId that relates to TeacherId in table teacher.

Comment: This is called Cascading.[ALTER TABLE table_constraint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of approaches:

If you are not using ORM:

1. Define cascade delete on foreign key constraint in SQL Server, then you need to send just delete query on `Teacher` table.
2. Create method which will get students based on teachers, then delete them, then delete teachers.

If you are using ORM:

1' In EF (and in other ORMs I guess) you can specify cascade delete, so ORM will handle for you situation, where you delete teachers.

2' Using ORM, get students' entities, delete them and then delete teachers

I think best for you will be option 1. as you didn't mention any ORMs. In this case read this: [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)

Comment: Do you really need this? This type of constraint should always be placed at DB end and never in your app layer.

Comment: @Rahul I fully agree, I just presented different approaches, as every rule has its own exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to delete your current FK constraint and add a new one with ON DELETE CASCADE enabled.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE Test
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_teacher
FOREIGN KEY (teacherID)
REFERENCES Test2 (teacherID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

After when you delete a row from the teachers' table it will delete all the rows in the student one where you have a relationship

Comment: Giving error "Foreign key 'fk_teacher' references invalid column 'StudentTeacherId' in referencing table 'teacher'"

Comment: @Ghost that you will have to figure out yourself. do some research .. read the documentation and stop expecting spoon feeding

Comment: @Ghost this is an example, you did not provide data example so I used test parameters. You will have to use the one you have in your DB